# Visualize services in rqt_graph

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, service, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
is there a way to visualize services in rqt? Like it is done with topics?

I'm using groovy and Python

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167971/visualize-services-in-rqt_graph/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick google search turns up: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_service_caller . Does this do what you want?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-21**:
Sorry i meant using rqt_graph, visualizing it as a box binding two nodes, the service client and server. I don't think rqt_service_caller is what I need.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-21**:
I don't think the list of clients for a service is available for introspection at all.